# Are there any utility libraries for LWC development?

Tags: lightning-web-components, libraries

Each time I develop LWCs I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel with wrapping apex requests in simpler functions or by providing custom error handling (with showing toasts etc.).

Maybe there are some utility-like projects (like [Apache Commons for Java](https://commons.apache.org/)) for LWC already? Do you know any?

Comment: For error handling here is [ldsUtils](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils)

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that for now there are no so many projects for extending LWC functionality. Possibly because the successor of Aura Components is nearly perfect ;)

What I have found so far:

### [Lightning Web Components Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)

> A collection of easy-to-digest code examples for Lightning Web
> Components. Each recipe demonstrates how to code a specific task in
> the fewest lines of code possible, while following best practices. A
> View Source link takes you right to the code in GitHub. From Hello
> World to data access and third-party libraries, there is a recipe for
> that!

Not exactly an extension library, but contains many great examples of how to write our LWC code in a good-quality way.

### [Salesforce Lookup Component](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc)

> This is a generic & customizable lookup component built using
> Salesforce [Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc) and [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) style. It does not rely
> on third party libraries and you have full control over its
> datasource.

It may come handy as there's still no standard LWC with lookup functionality.